# Execute a java script to make an element visible

Tags: c#, html, selenium

I'm trying to automate the use of a website using Selenium, at one time I want to click on a hidden button defined this way :

```
<body>
    <div class="smenu" id="smenu4">
        <input tabIndex="-1" type="button" onclick="SearchEng" value="FindEng" />
        <!--> Lots of inputs <!-->
    </div>
</body>
```

I already tried to simply click the button, but it doesn't work. I can select it and retrieve information though. That's why I'm now trying to run a javascript to make the button visible before clicking it. Here is my code :

```
IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id='smenu4']/input[@value=FindEng"));
String js = "arguments[0].style.height='auto'; arguments[0].style.visibility='visible';";
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript(js, element);
```

The thing is nothing happens when I launch it. Is it possible that I can't run scripts ? Can you run them on any website ? - I use internet explorer 11, windows 7. Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inspect the element in your Browser and check that what is the reason that the element is invisible. Or just simply compare the element when it is visible or not. Possible reasons:

- The element is not in the DOM yet.
- The element hasn't got width and/or height.
- `visibility` parameter. (http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_visibility.asp)
- `display` parameter.  (http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp)

When you know the reason, you will know the solution :)

Comment: Humm, I'm kinda ashamed... the element was visible all along, just white on a white background haha

Comment: I upvoted this because the DISPLAY parameter was absent from this and other examples of javascript to set visibility. Including this caused the javascript code execution to properly display the button I was seeking to show. Thanks